# Writing a conditional statement that modifies the original object, setting boundaries on a risk score

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am currently trying to take a risk score that is between ~(-0.5) and ~1.5 and put boundaries on it so that if it is below 0 it will be set to zero and if it is above 1 it will be set to 1. I have yet to find an example where the initial object is the one that is changed, as I do not wish to just create a flag or separate objects that I will have to consolidate later. sample pic of my data below[1]

[image: 1]

I have been trying the following code, it has the issue of setting every single row to 1, i am not sure how to get it to evaluate each row on an individual basis and either round it or leave it alone, based on the condition

```
if df["Risk Score"].loc <= 0:
    df["Risk Score"] = 0

elif df["Risk Score"].loc >= 1:
    df["Risk Score"] = 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and enhancing your question. Please show us examples, what you’ve tried (in code), and the exact problem you’re running into (unexpected output, exceptions, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html) method (works in `pandas` 21 and higher):

```
df["Risk score"].clip(lower=0, uppper=1, inplace=True)
```

In older versions of `pandas` you can do either

```
df["Risk score"] = df["Risk score"].clip(lower=0, uppper=1)
```

or the most obvious

```
df.loc[df["Risk score"] < 0, "Risk score"] = 0
df.loc[df["Risk score"] > 1, "Risk score"] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. just to mention, not sure if it my version of pandas or not, but the inplace argument was not needed and threw an error. everything worked perfectly after I removed

Comment: Just curious and trying to understand the syntax but in the last case where you have df.loc[df["Risk score"] < 0, :] = 0 what does the ", :" portion mean, in a literal sense?

Comment: @mitch, it was my error =) It means "all columns", which is, generally, wrong.
See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing for the explanation